# Hollow Rectangle with Asterisks

Tags: python, rectangles

I know there are numerous way to do this but I am trying to print a rectangle using ranges and if else statements. My code is below works but only cause I have hard coded the spaces required in print statement at line 7. As soon as the values for num_rows or num_cols changes the spacing is off. What do I need to do to make it work?

```
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 6

for i in range(num_rows):
    print('*', end=' ')
    if i in range(1,num_rows -1):
        print('       ','*', end='')
else:
    for j in range(num_cols-1):
        print('*', end=' ')
print('')
```

I got the code to turn into the code below after tinkering but it still is not the right and doesn't work once I change the values for the row and cols variables. I am not sure what I need to do to my size variable to be flexible and work with any values for num_rows and num_cols. Is it possible to make this work using only what I have covered so far in my class which is basically whats above lol.  I have asked my teacher for help and he stated that I should try searching forums for help first. He stated that most developers do that everyday so I need to get used to asking help.

```
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 6
size =(num_rows  + 3)

for i in range(num_rows):
    print('*', end=' ')
    if i in range(1,num_rows -1):
        print( ' ' * size + '*', end='')
else:
    for j in range(num_cols-1):
        print('*', end=' ')
print('')
```

Comment: The only thing different between those two snippets is that in the second one you are inserting `size` spaces, correct?  Can you explain the logic behind using `size =(num_rows  + 3)`?

Comment: I the size variable cause without it the output is not correct. And yes the difference between the two iterations of code is on the second I decided to use a variable instead of just hard coding spaces.

Comment: Your posted code prints everything on a single line; even the first code block doesn't print a rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean? From my understanding prints everything on the first line and goes through the loop till it gets to the last print statement that starts a new line.

Comment: @negru08 I was specifically asking about the `num_rows + 3` calculation.  Because if you think about the logic there, that won't give you the correct amount of whitespace inside your rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python makes it easier to do more with less code.

You could make the rectangle like

```
print("* "*num_cols, end='')
print(("\n* "+"  "*(num_cols-2)+"* ")*(num_rows-2))
print("* "*num_cols)
```

Line 1 prints `num_cols` `*`s without a newline after that.
Line 2 prints `num_rows-2` lines where each line consists of a `*` at each end with `num_cols-2` number of (spaces) in between.
Line 3 prints the bottom of the rectangle.

Your program should work fine if the number of spaces printed is changed from

```
print( ' ' * size + '*', end='')
```

to

```
print( '  ' * (num_cols-2)+ '*', end='')
```

Two spaces are needed because you have `end=' '` in `print()`s before it. If their `end` is made `end=''`, one space would suffice.

Comment: While I agree there is a simpler way of doing this code . I am challenged to try and make this working using loop statements that involve range . The actual code started as this below and I had to modify it to print a hollow rectangle : 

    num_rows = 2
    num_cols = 3

   for i in range(num_rows):
    print('*', end=' ')
    for j in range(num_cols-1):
        print('*', end=' ')
    print('')

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work. Some how I had messed up my loop when I pasted it here. But after I realligned everything and used your statement it works!! Thank you.  Can you explain why the num_cols -2 is needed or how it works?

Comment: A `*` is printed on either ends of each line (other than the top-most and bottom-most lines) and there are `num_cols` columns. There are `num_cols-2` columns left to take care of.